Show that two smooth map $f,g:\mathbb{T}^2\to \mathbb{T}^2$ are not homotopic.
Let $f,g:\mathbb{T}^2\to \mathbb{T}^2$ be smooth maps s.t.
$$f(w,z)=(w,z),\quad g(w,z)=(z,\bar{w})$$
If $f$ homotopic to $g$, then must have $f^*=g^*:H_{dR}^1(\mathbb{T}^2)\to H_{dR}^1(\mathbb{T}^2)$. Note that $f^*=Id^*$, which means that $g^*(\omega)-\omega=dh$ for some $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)$. There is a coordinate $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\to (e^{ix},e^{iy})\in \mathbb{T}^2 $, then we have
$$\omega=\omega_1 dx+\omega_2dy$$
and
$$dg=\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{matrix}\right)$$
then we have
$$g^*(\omega)-\omega=(\omega_2-\omega_1)dx+(\omega_1+\omega_2)dy$$
if there exist some $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)$, it must satisfies
$$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=\omega_2-\omega_1\\
\frac{\partial h}{\partial y}=\omega_1+\omega_2\end{cases}$$
and $\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x\partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y\partial x}$. But if we take
$$\omega_1=x+y,\quad \omega_2=x-y$$
then
$$\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x\partial y}=-2\ne 2=\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial y\partial x}$$
which means that there exists $\omega\in H^1_{dR}(\mathbb{T}^2)$ s.t. $f^*(\omega)\ne g^*(\omega)$.
I'm not sure the above proof is valid, can someone help me check this? Thanks!

Here you are viewing $\mathbb T^2$ as ${(z,w)\in \mathbb C^2\mid |v|=|w|=1}$?

@Aaron yes, here i view $\mathbb{T}^2=\mathbb{S}\times \mathbb{S}={(z,w)\in \mathbb{C}^2:|z|=|w|=1}$.

You can simplify the problem as follows: Let $i : \mathbb S \to \mathbb T^2, i(w) = (w,1)$, and let $\mu : \mathbb T^2 \to \mathbb S, \mu(w,z) = w \cdot z$ be the multplication map. If $f, g$ were homotopic, then also $\bar f = \mu \circ f \circ i$ and  $\bar g = \mu \circ g \circ i$ would be homotopic. But $\bar f(w) = w$ and $\bar g(w) = \overline w$.

@PaulFrost yeh, your proof is concise.

Work with the generators for the cohomology. $f^*dx=dx$, $f^*dy=dy$, $g^*dx=dy$, $g^*dy=-dx$. If $f$ and $g$ were homotopic, then $dx$ would be cohomologous to $dy$ (and $dy$ would be cohomologous to $-dx$). But $dx$ and $dy$ are not cohomologous, as the their integrals over $S^1\times\{\text{pt}\}$ are different.
